# How to access content of slot in another child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-loader

Following problem:

I have a Vue.js component which relies on its parent's DOM. But the moment the prop gets passed, it (`this.$el`) is undefined, probably because it's not yet mounted then.

My component's vue template file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <md-card>
    <md-card-content>
      <ol>
        <li v-for="item in headings(content)">
          <a :href="`#${item.id}`">{{ item.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['content'],
    methods: {
      headings(content) {
        // DOM element is used
        // At this moment, `content` is undefined
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

The component that uses the one above includes this piece of code:

```
<article-index :content="this.$el"></article-index>
```

I thought of waiting for the parent component to be mounted, but that way I can't seem to keep the template like above, because it would always try to access the method (or variable) instantly.

How can I solve this?

Edit:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left"><article-index :content="this.$el"></article-index></div>
    <div class="article"><slot></slot></div>
    <div class="right"><slot name="aside"></slot></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here's the parent component's template. The only thing I actually need is the `.article` div, or the slot's contents.

Comment: Why are you passing `this.$el` in prop ?

Comment: @saurabh Because I need to access the DOM element in order to do execute querySelector. How would you do it?

Comment: I will try to pass a vue variable there, can you add your HTML of parent DOM as well, and point out what exactly you want to access.

Comment: @saurabh Did so

Comment: @saurabh I see you edited the title... Well, I don't know how I access the slot DOM anyway 

Comment: @saurabh Obviously [vm.$slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots)?

Comment: Yes you got it, I was creating a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/hd1n41he/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it using `this.$slots`, in the parent component's mount function you can access `this.$slots` and assign it to some variable which can be passed to `article-index` component.

Following code prints the passed slots:

```
Vue.component('wrapper', {
    name: 'Wrapper',
  template: `<div><slot></slot></div>`,
  mounted () {
    this.$slots.default.forEach(vnode => { 
        console.log(vnode)
    })
  }
})
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/hd1n41he/).

Comment: So I can't use methods like querySelector like that, right?

Comment: You can access the HTML of `vnode` using `vnode.elm`. http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/hd1n41he/1/

Comment: * because the element's not yet mounted.

Comment: But again, "it would always try to access the method (or variable) instantly" (see the question) if I v-for over the headings.

Comment: @22samuelk Not sure how it is working, it is printing in console: http://jsfiddle.net/hd1n41he/2/

Comment: @22samuelk See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd1n41he/4/) which puts the content of slot in a variable and prints in the view separately.

Comment: That's basically the solution I was able to figure out myself, see the answer. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @saurabh I was able to find out that I can access the slot I'm passing to the child directly.

But the core problem remained: The component was not mounted at that moment.

So I changed how I'm accessing the passed slot.

Instead of the parent element, I'm now passing the default slot in the parent component.

Since the [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots) prop is an Array of `VNode` objects, I cannot use any DOM methods on them. But since a `VNode`'s elm property contains the actual DOM element, I'm using that instead.

Again, the problem: it's not mounted yet.

That's why the `v-for` now points to the `headings` data, not the method, which removed.
Instead, I added a [mounted()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) method, which automatically gets called by Vue when the components got mounted.

When that method gets called, the slot has been mounted, so I can access their `elm` properties. In my case, there are multiple default slots, so the `slots` array has more than one items. To make it possible to call a specific `querySelectorAll`, I've added some functional [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) magic.

Edit: Since it makes more sense to directly access querySelector on the rendered content, I'm now passing the `$refs` attribute instead of `$slots`.
Even though I only need `$refs.article`, if I pass it directly, I'll get undefined. By passing `this.$refs` as a whole, the child component can access the article ref even if it doesn't exist before mounting.

So this is my new parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <article-index :refs="this.$refs"></article-index>
    </div>
    <div class="article" ref="article"><slot></slot></div>
    <div class="right"><slot name="aside"></slot></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the child:

```
<template>
  <md-card>
    <md-card-content>
      <ol>
        <li v-for="item in headings">
          <a @click="scroll(item.id)" :href="hash">
            {{ item.name }}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</template>
<script>
  import dashify from 'dashify';

  export default {
    props: ['refs'],
    data: () => ({
      headings: {},
      hash: location.hash,
    }),
    methods: {
      scroll(to) {
        this.refs.article.querySelector(`#${to}`).scrollIntoView();
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      const elements = Array.from(this.refs.article.querySelectorAll('h2'));
      elements.forEach(node => node.id = dashify(node.innerText));

      this.headings = elements.map(node => ({
        name: node.innerText,
        id: node.id,
      }));
    },
  };
</script>
```